# macOS app for showing external HDD usage statistics?

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, external-disk

I'm planning on selling a used external HDD on eBay.  Are there any applications for Mac out there (preferably free) that can show me statistics about the usage history for the drive so that I can let potential buyers know the condition more precisely?

Comment: It may be worth you clarifying just what you mean by *usage statistics*, otherwise you may get answers that don't really help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By usage stats I'm assuming you mean SMART stats...

[DriveDx](https://binaryfruit.com/drivedx) has a trial version that will show SMART stats. But you have to load a kext to see USB attached disks. That's a common issue with all the 3rd party programs.

It works well, and will allow you to do short & extended self-tests even in the trial version. It will save a report you could email to your potential buyer (Actions | Save Drive Health Report).

Comment: @1dareu2mov3 I’ve used DriveDx with WD My Passport successfully. The other suggestions of adapters will not work with those disks if you pop them from the enclosure as they are hard wired USB3 straight onto the disk PCB. No SATA on the newer ones at least.

Answer (score 1):

In short...

No.

It's not so much a problem with an App that can get this information (SMART info), it is a problem with the USB to SATA controller itself providing the necessary interface to actually get the info.  See this [relevant answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/295199/119271) for reference.

Your best bet is to get a [Thunderbolt to eSATA adapter](http://radnex.us/thunderbolt-to-eSATA-adapter) and just use the built in commands on your Mac:

`diskutil info diskX | grep -i smart`

or an App like [Disk Warrior](https://alsoft.com/DiskWarrior/) or [Disk Drill](https://www.cleverfiles.com/) (any drive diagnostic app will work, technically).

What I do is I have an old Dell PC for testing out different components.  I have FreeBSD installed on a small drive and use the second/third SATA ports for testing/cloning drives.

Comment: Wow.  The Thunderbolt to eSATA adapter is very expensive - definitely not worth it.  So, without that, is it basically impossible to get stats pertaining to the usage history of the external drive?

Comment: Not impossible per se, but it very much depends on what the USB-SATA bridge is capable of doing.  In other words....some will work, some won't.

Comment: Ah, okay.  Well, I'll see if I'm able to access SMART information for my WD My Passport without having to use a Thunderbolt to eSATA adapter.  @Andy Griffiths recommended DriveDx in his answer, so I'll try that.